# Laravel 5.8: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$usr_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have Many To Many relationships between User Model & Wallet Model:

**Wallet.php**:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id');
}
```

And **User.php**:

```
public function wallets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');;
}
```

Then at Blade, I tried this:

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $wallet->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $wallet->pivot->balance }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$wallet->users()->id]) }}" class="fa fa-exchange text-dark mt-1"></a></td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No wallet exist</td>
    @endforelse
```

As you can see I have passed two parameters as route name `user.WalletTransaction` which is a link:

```
{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$wallet->users()->usr_id]) }}
```

And on **web.php**:

```
Route::get('wallet/transaction/{wallet}/{user}', 'Wallet\UserWalletController@WalletTransaction')->name('user.WalletTransaction');
```

But it shows me this error:

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$usr_id**

However `usr_id` is the id of users at `users` table:

[image]

And the pivot table structure, `user_wallet`, goes like this:

[image]

So how can I properly add the user id to that link?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks.

> **UPDATE #1**:

Result of `<a href="{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->id]) }}" class="fa fa-exchange text-dark mt-1" />` shows two links!

[image]

Comment: Well your wallet "belongsToMany" users, so which user are you trying to access with `wallet->users()->usr_id` you have many users in `wallet->users()`that's why it's not working i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wallet->users()` returns a collection, so you need to iterate over it like you're iterating over `wallets`

```
@forelse($wallet->users() as $user)
  <td>
    <a href="{{ route('user.WalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->id]) }}" class="fa fa-exchange text-dark mt-1" />
  </td>
[...]
```

Comment: Since `$wallet->users()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`. To get an iterable collection, shouldn't you call get? So: `$wallet->users()->get()` or simply `$wallet->users` to get a collection? Downvoted your solution since it does not work. If you change it, will upvote.

Comment: Thanks but it shows me two links instead of one, I just added an **UPDATE #1** about this

Comment: @loctoj if it's showing to links, it means that you have two users associated with that wallet.

Comment: @loctoj I can't help you more than I already did. I've provided a working solution from a logical standpoint; can't say what's your issue now, but I'm 100% sure my solution is fine for the problem you've described.